# accessing second element in regexp_matches array

Tags: arrays, regex, postgresql

I have a table with a field that has strings like this:

> US 19;PA 65

I need to split this out into four new fields like:

> 'US ','19','PA','65'

regexp_matches seems to be the ticket. I can use the following statements to extract 'US' into one field and '19' into another.

```
UPDATE osm_motorway SET shieldcl1 = (regexp_matches(ref, '^[A-Z]+', 'i'))[1];

UPDATE osm_motorway SET shieldlbl1 = (regexp_matches(ref, '\d+', 'i'))[1];
```

But I can't get 'PA' and '65' into their own fields with the following. They return empty:

```
UPDATE osm_motorway SET shieldcl2 = (regexp_matches(ref, '^[A-Z]+', 'i'))[2];

UPDATE osm_motorway SET shieldlbl2 = (regexp_matches(ref, '\d+', 'i'))[2];
```

How do I access the second match with regexp_matches?

Comment: `select regexp_matches('US 19;PA 65', '([[:alpha:]]+)\s*([[:digit:]]+);([[:alpha:]]+)\s*([[:digit:]]+)');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both patterns in an alternative and the flag 'g' for global searching to get all matches at once:

```
select regexp_matches('US 19;PA 65', '[A-Z]+|\d+', 'ig');

 regexp_matches 
----------------
 {US}
 {19}
 {PA}
 {65}
(4 rows)
```

Use this query to convert the result into an array:

```
select array(select (regexp_matches('US 19;PA 65', '[A-Z]+|\d+', 'ig'))[1]);

     array     
---------------
 {US,19,PA,65}
(1 row)
```

Create the function for convenience:

```
create or replace function split_ref(ref text)
returns text[] language sql as $$
    select array(select (regexp_matches(ref, '[A-Z]+|\d+', 'ig'))[1])
$$;
```

and use it in your update statement:

```
update osm_motorway
set 
    shieldcl1  = (split_ref(ref))[1],
    shieldlbl1 = (split_ref(ref))[2],
    shieldcl2  = (split_ref(ref))[3],
    shieldlbl2 = (split_ref(ref))[4];
```

---

An alternative way to split the string (without regexp):

```
select string_to_array(translate('US 19;PA 65', ' ', ';'), ';');

 string_to_array 
-----------------
 {US,19,PA,65}
(1 row)
```